# Downgrade of mysql 5.6 to 5.5

Tags: 14.04, mysql, services, versions, downgrade

Hello i have `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`. I need to downgrade it for `mysql 5.5`. What are the procedures necessary for this operation. My O.S is Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Presumably you want `sudo apt install mysql-client-5.5`. It should mark `5.6` for removal, and `5.5` for installation.

Comment: @Hi-Angel nope not likely to work without some extra editing of configuration files. It will keep the settings and 5.6 uses things 5.5 will see as a problem. - export your databases if you need those. - "purge" 5.6 - install 5.5 - import database into sql.